# Display request permission dialog only when fragment is visible in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-permissions

I have a ViewPager with 3 tabs, in each of these tab I can have 2-3 or 4 sub tabs.

When opening the activity, all the tabs (all the fragments) are loaded. Some of the fragments are asking some permissions (can be same permission for different fragment).

My main problem is all the request permission pop up will be displayed when opening this activity. Event if the first fragment visible doesn't need any permission.
Is there is a way to ask permission only when the fragment is visible? Or the only solution is to track the click on Tab and the ViewPager OnPageChangeListener?

Comment: That's how the `ViewPager` works. It will instantiate the first visible fragment, and a few on both sides - so if you have 3 fragments, all three will be instantiated,and they will all request their permissions if you're doing it in `onCreateView()`

If you manage to change it's `DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES` member from 1 to 0, you should get your desired effect I guess.

Comment: Yes I know it is the purpose of the viewpager. Problem with offscreen page 0, my first page is a call to server, and navigate between page will make a call each time we go to first fragment... I was wondering if the view pager is giving use when page is shown, maybe I should use OnPageChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

Override a method in *all* the fragments( **except the First fragment** ) ...

```
   @Override
   setUserVisibilityHint(...) {
    super..  
      if(getActivity()!=null) {

         requestPermissions();
      }
   }
```

1st time at the **activity start** it wont request permission *because* `getActivity()` is `null` for all the other fragments...from the 2nd time onwards...it will request permission..

**Note** :- It will request permission *as soon as* you **swipe** across your pages in the `ViewPager`.

Comment: I tried, there is some issue, setUserVisibilityHint will be call even if the page is not visible to user. For example the tab2-1 will be call, but working for tab 2-2

Answer (score 0):

There is an argument **visible**. Use it to determine visibility.

```
override fun setUserVisibleHint(visible: Boolean) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible)
    if (visible && activity != null) {
        checkPermissions()
    }
}
```